# Auto append list items in dictionary with default values python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, default-value

I am trying to create an attendance logger where I create a dictionary which I fill with student names. The names will be lists where I append their class attendance data (whether they attended class or not). The code I have so far is displayed below`

```
#! /bin/python3
#add student to dict
def add_student(_dict):
    student=input('Add student :')
    _dict[student]=[]
    return _dict

#collect outcomes
def collector(student,_dict, outcome):
    _dict[student].append(outcome)
    return _dict

#counts target
def count(_dict,target):
    for i in _dict: 
        # records total attendance names
        attendance_stat = len(_dict[i])
        # records total instances absent
        freq_of_absence=_dict[i].count(target)
        # records percentage of absence
        perc_absence = float((freq_of_absence/attendance_stat)*100)
        print(i,'DAYS ABSENT =',freq_of_absence)
        print('TOTAL DAYS: ', i, attendance_stat)
        print('PERCENTAGE OF ABSENCE:', i, str(round(perc_absence, 2))+'%')

#main function
def main():
    #date=input('DATE: ')
    outcomes=['Y','N']
    student_names = {}
    try:
        totalstudents = int(input('NO. OF STUDENTS: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('input an integer')
        totalstudents = int(input('NO. OF STUDENTS: '))
    while len(student_names) < totalstudents:
        add_student(student_names)
    print(student_names)
    i = 0
    while i < totalstudents:
        i = i + 1
        target='Y'
        student=str(input('student :'))
        outcome=str(input('outcome :'))
        collector(student,student_names,outcome)
    count(student_names,target)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

`
The code works well so far but the problem is when the number of students is too large, time taken to input is extensive cutting in on class time. Since the number of absentees is usually less than those present, is it possible to select from the dictionary students absent which will append the value Y for each selected absent, while appending N to the remaining lists in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but I think it will help. Instead of asking the user to input a name each time for the second part, why not just print the name yourself, and only ask for the outcome? Your last `while` loop would then become a for loop instead, like this:

```
for student_name in student_names:
    outcome = input("Outcome for {}: ".format(sudent_name))
    collector(student_name, student_names, outcome)
```

You could also add some logic to check if outcome is an empty string, and if so, set it to 'N'. This would just allow you to hit enter for most of the names, and only have to type in 'Y' for the certain ones that are absent. That would look like this:

```
for student_name in student_names:
    outcome = input("Outcome for {}: ".format(sudent_name))
    if outcome = "":
        outcome = "N"
    collector(student_name, student_names, outcome)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated. I can now keep track of my students and make sure none gets left behind.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind marking this as the solution if it helped you?